# Swap array elements show error: Simultaneous accesses to but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I want to swap my array elements:

```
swap(&(self.profileImages[0]), &(self.profileImages[2]))
```

But I get this error:

> Simultaneous accesses to 0x102944a80, but modification requires exclusive access

Comment: Dude! Thank you sooooooo much this is a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lots of searching: As [Whats-new-in-Swift-4](https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4/blob/master/Whats-new-in-Swift-4.playground/Pages/swapAt.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift) describe I found that in **swift4** I should use this code:

```
self.profileImages.swapAt(0, 2)
```

Comment: *After lots of searching I found that in swift4 I should use this code* - posting an answer less than a minute after posting a question is indeed a lot of searching.

Comment: @mag_zbc I searched but I found nothing in stackoverflow. when I found my answer I decide to post my question & answer